# Google Chrome - Inspect CSS Grid on reload?

Tags: google-chrome

There is this Inspect CSS Grid feature.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/grid

Is there a way to keep the existing settings/selections upon page reload?

Use-case:

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp
- make grid/layout selections
- reload the page (keep the previous highlights)

[image]